# Proving the formula for the cardinality of cartesian products.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Consider sets A and B where |A|=m and |B|=n. Prove by induction on n for a given m that |A*B| = mn for all m,n ∈ N where A*B = cartesian product.

My attempt : Base Case - consider when n = 0 so B is the empty set.  Clear then for all sets A, |A* empty set| = 0 = 0*m.  Therefore true for n=0
Consider also when n=1 clearly then B contains 1 element, b.  Then A*B = {(a,b)|a ∈ A} and so clearly A*B has m elements = m*1.

Inductive Step - Suppose |B|=k , k ∈ N and that |A*B|=mk is true. We must show the formula holds for n=k+1.  Consider the set C = B ∪ {x} (disjoint union). Clearly then |C|=k+1 and A*C = A*(B ∪ {x}) = A*B ∪ A*{x} and so |A*C| = |A*B| + |A*{x}| = mk + m (by inductive hypothesis and by showing what we showed in our base case) = m(k+1) as the formula predicts.

Therefore true for all natural numbers n.

Is this fine ??

Comment: I think you want a base case of $n=1$. Reason being, you want your base case to contain a fact involving $m$ that you can use later in the proof.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense

Comment: If you edit your post and change that, I can take a look at your proof if you'd like?

Comment: Edited it.  Think it is fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an understanding of what the proof needs to look like, but I have a number of suggestions to make.Off the bat, I'd do away completely with the portion of your proof that says

"consider when n = 0 so B is the empty set. Clear then for all sets A, |A* empty set| = 0 = 0*m. Therefore true for n=0 Consider also"

And just open with

"Base Case: Let $n=1$. Then clearly..."

and continue from there. For the induction step, I would also due away with the line

"Suppose |B|=k ,$k\in \Bbb{N}$ and that $|AB|=mk$ is true. We must show the formula holds for $n=k+1.$"

And replace that whole part with

"Suppose for all $n$ where $1<n \leq k$ and $|B|=n$ that $|AB|=mn$ holds."

After this sentence, then introduce your set $C = B \cup \{x \}$. Make sure you specify that $x \neq b$ for any $b \in B$. Next, you wrote above this equality: $$AC = A(B \cup\{x\}) = AB \cup A\{x\}$$ I would be careful with this notation, and would instead write $$AC = \{(a,c):a \in A, \space c \in C \} \\ = \{(a,b)\vee (a,x) :a \in A, \space b \in B \} \\ = \{(a,b) :a \in A, \space b \in B \} \cup \{(a,x) :a \in A \}$$ Now by the induction step you know $$\left|\{(a,b) :a \in A, \space b \in B \}\right|=mk$$ and by the base case you know $$\left|\{(a,x) :a \in A\}\right|=m$$ so now argue that $$|AC| = mk+m = m(k+1)$$ where you can cite the fact that $x$ was not an element in $B$ to help make this argument.

Comment: No problem; happy to help :)